# CSS is not working if nested

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-framework-7

I have a webapp made with Framework7 - but I think the issue is CSS related. The issue is that the badges on the tabs disappear the first time I change the icon of the tab.

I just don't see why. As long as I don't change the icon the badge works.

HTML

```
 <a href="#tablink" id="tab" class="link no-animation"><i class="icon f7-icons" id="tabIcon" style="color:white">gear<span id="tabText"></span></i></a>
```

JS to change icon (works)

```
document.getElementById('tabIcon').innerHTML = "gear_fill";
```

JS to change and activate the badge (doesn't work after changing icon - before it does)

```
$$.get(serverAddress + 'source/source.php',
function(data) { if (data==""){$$('#tabText').removeClass('badge bg-red'); document.getElementById('tabText').innerHTML = data;}
else{ $$('#tabText').addClass('badge bg-red'); document.getElementById('tabText').innerHTML = data;}});
```

The error I get in console is this:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('tabText').innerHTML = data')

I think it could be related to the nesting...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `element.innerHTML = "something"` will replace everything inside that element. in this case `gear<span id="tabText"></span>` becomes "something". So one solution could be to `document.getElementById('tabIcon').innerHTML = 'gear_fill<span id="tabText"></span>';` (I must add that I don't think it's a very pretty method though...)

Comment: `document.getElementById('tabIcon').childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'gear_fill';` should change only the text. I think that is better, but still not pretty.

Comment: Thanks, the second part works. Pretty enough in that case. :)